How can I accumulate past 256 in a framebuffer texture?
As a way to estimate screenspace density of a set of particles, I'm trying to do some splatting: render a circle of fixed radius around each particle, accumulating, to get a count of how many particles are within that radius of each point. If I could be confident that my count stayed under 256 then I could easily use the stencil buffer for this, but unfortunately it could be larger. My approach was to render to texture, using R32UI as the format for my buffer (since that's ostensibly guaranteed to be renderable), UNSIGNED_INT as the format, etc., then turn on blending with a blendfunc of (ONE, ONE) and render the value 1 to every pixel for each circle to try to accumulate. I assumed this would work because the spec seems to suggest that the integer values should be treated as 1/(2^32-1) for blending purposes, then converted back to integers for storage, but unfortunately the buffer doesn't seem to count past 1; even with multiple circles layered that's the value that shows up when I try to read the accumulated pixels. Is there another way of doing this counting, or am I barking up the wrong tree entirely?

There can be implicit conversions when reading and writing buffers so the details of how the reads and writes are being done matter.

@pmw1234 What additional specific details would help here?

Can you add code of the texture creation, the texture read (back to CPU), the fragment shader and texture binding to shader

Can you use blending in floating point buffers?
